# Change text color when hover over background image in same div

Tags: html, css, hover

In a `div` tag I have a background image and below that there is a text link as well.
The background image and text link are wrapped in the same `<a>` tag.

Now what I am trying to do is to change the color of the text link both when the mouse is over the background image or the text link.

What I achieved so far is to change only the text color when hover over the text but cannot do it when hover over the image.

Any ideas where I should apply the hover property? Tried a hundreds of variations and still cannot do it.

Here is the test demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bradg/65UHg/

And the code, it is a bit long sorry for that.

**EDIT** Updated the CSS code and removed some unrelated to the problem lines

CSS:

```
.make_cat_img_thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 4px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
          transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
          text-decoration:none;
 }

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.text-muted {
  color: #999;
}

.text-muted:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.c-cover-image { 
    width:120px; 
    height:120px; 
    background-size:100% 100%; 
    margin:auto; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-position:center center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="make_catalogue" style="padding-top:10px;">

    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 c-mobile c-mbottom">
        <a href="google.com" class="make_cat_img_thumbnail">
            <div style="background-image:url(../images/ctg/10085_1.jpg)" class="c-cover-image">
            </div>
            <br>
            <p class="text-center text-muted">Some Text</p>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: It's a little hard to follow your question. You need to specify `the text color when hover over the text` via exact id or class name.

Comment: I need to specify the text color when I hover over the background image, which is over the "Some Text" tag.

Comment: You need pure css solution without javascript involved?

Comment: Best solution would be CSS, to keep it simple but if not possible via CSS will look for other solution. Do you have something simple in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since image is in background you cannot use it for hover. Instead use this:

```
.make_catalogue:hover a, .make_catalogue:hover a p {
color:orange;
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this changes only the color of the line under the text.

Comment: This is because you have p tag in your link. I edited my code above + http://jsfiddle.net/7FU49/

Comment: Yes! This was the answer I needed. Never thought that all is because of the p tag. There is just one change required - since there will be more than one of those boxes with image and text if the style is applied to `make_catalogue` the text of all boxes turn into orange on hover. So I applied your solution to `c-mbottom` instead and now the text in each box is changed separately. I am choosing your answer as the right one, you might want to change `make_catalogue` to `c-mbottom` if you have time. And thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
.make_catalogue a img:hover {
   color:orange;
   font-color:orange;
   text-decoration:underline;
}
```

To this:

```
.make_catalogue a:hover
 {
  color:orange;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

By the way, `font-color` isn't a valid CSS property, the color of the text is defined by the `color` property.

Comment: this was one of the unfortunate tries to make the text orange. Changing it with your code does not work either:(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.c-cover-image:hover .text-muted{
    color: #00f;
}
```

Comment: You can also try adding priority with `color: #00f !important`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.make_cat_img_thumbnail:hover p {
color:orange;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/65UHg/6/